# how to make WinEdt the default editor for `.tex` files?

Tags: windows, winedt

I want to open all files `.tex` with Winedt 5.6 but all files `.tex` is opening with Texworks. If I select the option Choose default program and I select the WinEdt, it doen't appear in the list. Even if I click to the button "Browse" and then I select the path where the "WinEdt.exe" file exists, the problem is not solved.

Could you please help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can open the `WinEdt Configuration Wizard`, and click on the `File Types Associations` tab, like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Refer the below image:

[image]

As per the screenshot, if you select the option `Choose default program` and then select the `WinEdt`, also select the option `Always use the selected program to open this kind of file`, thats all, refer the below image:

[image]

Comment: I make this but the icon winedt don't appear in open with.

Comment: @Student Sorry to ask, whether you installed WinEdt into the system?

Comment: No it is installed and now I use it

Comment: If it is not shown, then click the button "Browse" and then select the path where the "WinEdt.exe" file exists...

Comment: Yes I clicked to 'Browse' and even if I seclected "WinEdt.exe"  it doesn't appear in the list.

Comment: @Student Do you have Admin rights in that system?

Comment: No..this problem start when I uninstalled Winedt 5.6 in order to replace it with Winedt 10.2 but since I don't have the registration code of Winedt 10.2 I uninstalled it and I have reinstalled Winedt 5.6.